# Using more lines than the window has with ncurses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, scrollbars

I have recently been introduced to `ncurses` for asynchronous keyboard key listening, and getting on well with it. One issue i'm facing is that you can only have text on the visible screen, no scrollbars. I was wondering if its possible to keep using `ncurses` as it is so lovely, but have the program still keep the scrollbars rather than getting to the last line and staying there.

Comment: I assume you mean, making a GUI terminal program apply its own scroll-bars, by extending a curses display taller than the window? (Not, adding scroll-bars within the curses environment?)
Don't have a chance to experiment right now, but can't you just adjust `extern int LINES` to the size you'd like…? (Of course, this would probably break your program on physical terminals, e.g. Linux text consoles)

Comment: @BRPocock No, the idea is not to add an element within the curses environment, but to make the program move onto a new line (beyond the range of the terminal window, forcing a scrollbar to appear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[scroll()](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_scroll.3.asp).  You have to set scrollok(win, TRUE) first.  Actually if you just want to spew data like a normal terminal you only need to set [scrollok()](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=scrollok) by itself.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    initscr();

    scrollok(stdscr,TRUE);

    while(1)
    {
        printw("%d - lots and lots of lines flowing down the terminal\n", i);
        ++i;
        refresh();
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```