# How to scroll a window (other than stdscreen) in ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses, tui

I saw this answer researching to solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407120/2570513, but, it works only on stdscreen. I implemented this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 2, height, width;
    WINDOW *new;

    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);
    new = newwin(height - 2, width - 2, 1, 1);

    scrollok(new,TRUE);

    while(1)
    {
        mvwprintw(new, i, 2, "%d - lots and lots of lines flowing down the terminal", i);
        ++i;
        wrefresh(new);
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't scroll. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mvprintw` function first attempts to move the cursor to the indicated position, e.g., with [`wmove`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html).  The `wmove` function never causes scrolling, and the attempt to move it past the bottom line of the window fails (quoting from `wmove` manual):

> These routines return ERR upon failure and OK (SVr4 specifies only "an integer value other than ERR") upon successful completion.
>
> Specifically,  they  return an error if the window pointer
>   is null, or if the position is **outside** the window.

Instead, to do scrolling you must write text with a *newline* character (i.e., `'\n'`) at the bottom of the window.  `wprintw` is useful; in turn it calls `waddch` (quoting from the latter's manual):

> The  **addch**,  **waddch**, **mvaddch** and **mvwaddch** routines put the
>   character *ch* into the given window at its  current  window
>   position,  which  is then advanced.  They are analogous to
>   **putchar** in stdio(3).  If the advance is at the right  margin:
>
> ...
>
> At the bottom of the current scrolling region, and  if
>   [**scrollok**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html)  is enabled, the scrolling region is scrolled
>   up one line.
>
> If *ch* is a tab, newline, or backspace, the cursor is moved appropriately within the window:
>
> ...
>
> Newline  does a [**clrtoeol**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html), then moves the cursor to the
>   window left margin on the  next  line,  scrolling  the
>   window if on the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you place the string on a certain position in the window by using `mvwprintw`, so when `i` gets bigger than the windowsize it's just not printed on the screen.

In order to use scolling you need to use `wprintw` which puts the text on the current cursor position.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 2, height, width;
    WINDOW *new;

    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);
    new = newwin(height - 2, width - 2, 1, 1);

    scrollok(new,TRUE);

    while(1)
    {
        wprintw(new, "%d - lots and lots of lines flowing down the terminal\n", i);
        ++i;
        wrefresh(new);
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to fill a window with content and then use the arrow keys to scroll up and down, you should have a look at [Pads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370377/scrolling-in-c-with-ncurses-pad)